# How can menu title be included in breadcrumbs?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have menu block  with title 'Content'. It has several links. Breadcrumbs are made throw template.php by splitting url. Is it possible to include menu name before last link (which is content title) in breadcrumbs? I need to make it for all custom menu block links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`drupal_get_title`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_title/7)

> The title is displayed on the page and in the title bar.

Alter breadcrumb code accordingly.

Comment: @YuriyKosyanchuk, Thanks. Well now select the answer as accepted by marking the tick sign below the up/down arrows.